# Pyspark job queue config precedence - spark-submit vs SparkSession.builder

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a shell script which runs a spark-submit command. I want to specify the resource queue name onto which the job runs.

When I use: 
`spark-submit --queue myQueue job.py` (here the job is properly submitted on 'myQueue')

But when I use: `spark-submit job.py` and inside `job.py` I create a spark session like: 
`spark=SparkSession.builder.appName(appName).config("spark.yarn.queue", "myQueue")` - In this case the job runs on default queue. Also on checking the configs of this running job on the spark UI, it shows me that queue name is "myQueue" but still the job runs on default queue only.

Can someone explain how can I pass the queue name in `sparkSession.builder` configs so that it takes into effect.

Using pyspark version 2.3